# Expected and Actual Values in Failed Protractor Test Cases

Tags: jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I have recently installed the `jasmine-spec-reporter` package in order to produce more verbose and helpful logging during execution of test suites.

I want to be able to log `expected` and `actual` values for failed test cases and was wondering if I needed to explicitly have a statement in the form of `expect(someCondition).toEqual(true);` in order for me to see these values.

For example, I have a function like the following:

```
it('should log in', function(done) {
    var customerNameElement;

    customerNameElement = element.all(by.xpath('some_xpath')).first();

    core.infoMessage(browser, JSON.stringify(params, undefined, 4));
    login.login(browser, undefined, undefined, getWaitTime())
        .then(function() {
             return browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.and(
                 function() { return core.isUnobscured(browser, customerNameElement); 
        }, protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(customerNameElement)), getWaitTime());
    })
    .catch(fail)
    .then(done);
});
```

I can still log the failure to the console but not in the form that I'd like. Does `jasmine-spec-reporter` handle this or do I have to add the statement from above in each test case?

Also, does the `fail` keyword in the `.catch()` have any properties I can use to my advantage? It comes from:

> // Type definitions for Jasmine 2.5.2 // Project: http://jasmine.github.io/

Thanks

Comment: Aren't expected and actual values already logged for failed test cases?  i.e. `expected true to be false`... `expected 1 to equal 2` etc.

Comment: @Gunderson, here is an example of what I get back:
`× should display the text element
      - Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, some_xpath)`
But then again, maybe there is no expected value for an xpath. Thoughts?
(This is for another test case, not the one listed above)

Comment: Well thats an ElementFinder error and it describes the problem you are facing (that element doesnt exist, so it cant perform whatever action you are trying to perform).  I'm not understanding what exactly you would want in place of that error?

Comment: I think that some `it` functions don't produce `expected` and `actual` values, such as the one above. For an `xpath` error, I agree with you, the error thrown is what should be produced. Is there a way to change `Expected 0 to be 1` to, `Expected false to be true` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding the below in protractor_config file: 
let SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;

exports.config = {
   // your config here ...

onPrepare: function () {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
      spec: {
        displayStacktrace: true
      
}
    }));
  
}
}

Also, add the print function in the `jasmineNodeOpts`section 
jasmineNodeOpts: {
   ...
   print: function() {}
}